# Application Insights no longer track dependencies entries from JS Client

Tags: client-side, azure-application-insights

We are using application insight to track our angular application. Everything was working perfectly. But without doing any changes in the application we are not seeing any AJAX dependencies anymore. The last tracked dependency was on 5th September 2017. 
However all page views and exceptions that we were sending from JS app-insight api are still logged and displayed correctly. Is something changed in the app insight api?

I saw that we were having old app insight snippet and the new snippet is changed, I even put the new snippet in our page but the dependencies are still not working. 
This is the latest code snippet that I am using now.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
    function i(config){t[config]=function(){var i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},u=document,e=window,o="script",s="AuthenticatedUserContext",h="start",c="stop",l="Track",a=l+"Event",v=l+"Page",y=u.createElement(o),r,f;y.src=config.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js";u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(y);try{t.cookie=u.cookie}catch(p){}for(t.queue=[],t.version="1.0",r=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];r.length;)i("track"+r.pop());return i("set"+s),i("clear"+s),i(h+a),i(c+a),i(h+v),i(c+v),i("flush"),config.disableExceptionTracking||(r="onerror",i("_"+r),f=e[r],e[r]=function(config,i,u,e,o){var s=f&&f(config,i,u,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+r](config,i,u,e,o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey:"XXX" // Replaced the actual key with XXX the key for privacy reason
    });

    window.appInsights=appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView();
</script>
```

Is something changed in the application insight?

Comment: i've forwarded this on to the team that owns the js sdk.  you might want to also post this as an issue on their github repo directly?  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will post the issue on github